# Vue.js devtools not showing

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, vuejs2, devtools, vue-devtools

Suddenly my Vue.js devtools stopped working. I had it in the chrome for like 2 years (since I started developing Vue.js). Now I can't see devtools in chrome. It happened yesterday just like that - I was using devtools for a while, then I was working on something else and after a while, I noticed something - devtools is away. Even though the extension is saying that devtools works:
[image]

---

Why it is not "my" problem:

1. I use it for 2 years with no problem, until now
2. It was working in the morning, then it "just" stopped
3. Now it doesn't work on **any** project, even I know it worked before
4. I'm not using production mode, minified version, etc... I compile it through webpack and worked before.
5. It doesn't work even on the simple-fresh Vue.js app *

---

Why I tried so far:

1. Hard-refresh website (close and reopen devtools of course)
2. Restart browser
3. Reinstall extension
4. Tried [this version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) and also [this bugfix version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bugfix-vuejs-devtools/niapgcaeadldbabakiifalfcidacihap)
5. Logout and login from the account
6. Enabled all settings for the extension:
   [image]

---

**OS**: macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)

**Browser**: 83.0.4103.61

**Vue.js DevTools**: 5.3.3

---

* Fresh Vue.js app code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue!'
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it still doesn't work (yes, the extension still says "Vue.js detected on this page. Open DevTools and..."):
[image]

Comment: Even on an application being created through vue-cli? Because the "fresh snippet" you sent Is using Vue on the browser

Comment: I don't use vue-cli at all. Even if it would work, all my projects would be unable to get it work, because they were not made with vue-cli? I need a solution for a browser vue, that's why I didn't even try vue-cli.

Comment: Yea, but I wanted to understand under which scenario it doesn't work, just trying to help man

Comment: And I appreciate that. Funny thing - it works well for all my colleagues, except that they didn't update their chrome yet.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling chrome, or downgrade it?

Comment: Not yet, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti I haven't reinstalled chrome, because I haven't got time for it... But all of a sudden it works now, I really didn't do anything with it. Weird.

Comment: Which version of vue.js are you using? If you have updated your Vue project to V3, you also need to update your dev tools.

Comment: This question is from May 28, 2020, Vue.js 3 was not out yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I experienced this, too, both for Chrome and Firefox.

The unfortunate solution for Chrome was updating it to the latest version (today, that is 83.0.4103.106, 64bit on Windows).

For Firefox (77.0.1, 64bit) I disabled all other extensions, loaded the page without Firefox Devtools open, then hit F12 and the Vue tab popped up.

In general, disabling any other extensions (think of "Ad Block Plus" or "I don't care about cookies" for example) might help.

**[EDIT]:** Adding another case I experienced, when the Vue tab does not show up in Chrome's Devtools:

1. load the page without Devtools open
2. press the Vue Devtools button in the extensions area (might say "Vue.js not detected", but don't let that bother you). In some setups, this step is crucial.
3. only *then* open Devtools by hitting F12. Vue tab should appear (check to the very right of all tabs, you can drag it to the left)

Comment: Since I'm not experiencing this anymore I consider updateing chrome was the solution :D

Comment: I'm having a similar problem where it says that it can detect vue but that I didn't build it in developer mode, but I absolutely did build it in developer mode, so I don't know what's going on... Did yours say that?

Comment: Thanks - your F12 solution works like magic!

Comment: Install Beta version of Vue dev tools works. Stable does not work.

Comment: @Čamo That should only be the solution if you use Vue 3. The stable version of vue devtools should work fine with Vue 2.

Comment: Yes but Vue 3 was released more than year ago.

Answer (score 4):

If using Vue 3, you need the new version of the extension that is currently still in beta https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en

Comment: the link does not work

Answer (score 1):

Well another reason why Vuejs devtools might not be showing is because you ran `npm run production` or `npm run dev` so in that case the extension will detect Vuejs but won't show in devtools.

So you'll have to either run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`.

Close devtools, reload page and open devtools

Comment: I'm running it through gulp+webpack and I do know I had development mode (because it is not possible to run the project on localhost in production, just in case I would do a mistake). Anyway, I haven't experienced it since.

Comment: Actually it's possible to run a production project locally, except for having different data

Comment: I know, I just made it like that on purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is I had to do Ctrl+C to quit current process, then run "php artisan serve" again, then Vue tool shows up in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me several times in Chrome. I just close the inspect and open it again to see Vue Devtools in inspect tabs.

Comment: Don't think it's a proper answer, no reasons/help provided. Just simple restart is not solution of problem.

Comment: I think it's not our problem to fix bug of vue.js dev tools. We can continue to work with the tool until next updates of it

Comment: There are info in question description that reopening page/inspector/browser don't help

Answer (score 0):

To me embedding VUE versionless via unpkg helps. It pulls the latest version. Now the browser Vue Devtools show up.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, and may it be helpful to someone ending up here: error in the code may hinder vue devtools from showing up. I encountered this when calling data from pinia store in `router/index.js`.