# Vuejs DevTools not showing panel in developer tools

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I cannot get the vue development tools to show it's panel.

I've tried deleting and re-installing the extension, Hard refreshing, closing the tools and opening again, adding `Vue.config.devtools = true;` and a combination of all of them and it still does not show the panel.  Any ideas?

I did notice that `__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` doesn't have a Vue value... but I don't have a working dev tool to see if that should be otherwise.

[image: console with extension showing it should be working]

macOS Catalina (version 10.15.5)

Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Did you close your broweser and relaunch it, too?

Comment: Could be a bug https://crbug.com/1093731 which is fixed in Chrome Canary which you can install separately.

Comment: Yes @T.Woody I did all the refreshing steps etc.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm for the link.

Comment: Please see the resolution to my problem below.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:  Turns out the devTool github repo had an even better answer:

```
const app = new Vue(vueConfig).$mount('#app');
window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.Vue = app.constructor;
```

See here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

---

Turns out it was a jest work around that was causing the problem.  My jest tests weren't working with my normal vue instance so I had to mock it with the `createLocalVue`.

```
const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter();
```

The problem was that some tests were not liking that I had two vue instances (the one in main.js) with a router.

So I added logic to only add the router if it wasn't a test:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

if (!process || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
}

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes,
});

const vueConfig = {
    render: (h) => h(App),
};

// excluding for jest tests
if (!process || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    vueConfig.router = router;
}

new Vue(vueConfig).$mount('#app');
```

Unfortunately the if around the Vue.use() is what broke it:

```
// removing this if() fixed it and the vue dev tools panel now shows up.
if (!process || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
}
```

Something about the way the dev tools inits needed the router to be installed.  I also wonder if they use a process with "test" or something.  Either way, this is resolved for me.  Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and able to solve by avoiding `vue.min.js` for development purpose. Use original version (`vue.js`) instead of the minify version.

Comment: but how can I do this?

Comment: How do you use Vue? - npm or CDN link ! if you are using CDN then use inside the script tag. As
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

1. load the page without Devtools open
2. press the Vue Devtools button in the extensions area (might say "Vue.js not
   detected", but don't let that bother you). In some setups, this step is
   crucial.
3. only then open Devtools by hitting F12. Vue tab should appear (check to the
   very right of all tabs, you can drag it to the left)

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446093/15265413